# XSLT version change from 1.0 to 3.0

Tags: xslt, version

I am new to xslt and we are using currently version 1.0, now we have to upgrade to version 3.0
what are the steps i have to follow? Is there any processor i need to replace or just all the xsl files will have new version like

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: You need a processor that supports XSLT 3.0.

Comment: You have to use an XSLT 3 processor, on the Java platform it might be as easy as putting Saxon 9.9 or 10 on the class path or in your Maven dependencies, on other platforms you will probably not have the same API supported by the XSLT 3.0 processor that your XSLT 1 processor supported.

Comment: @Martin, how do i know where is this processor? is it like some jar or setting ?

Comment: For information about Saxon go to www.saxonica.com. There are different versions for different platforms (Java, .NET, Node.js etc).